# How to reach a method of an object that implements Runnable in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, getter

I have an object called `OBJ`, that implements `Runnable`.
It has a few members, a constructor, a run() method and a getter for a certain count (one of the members).
In my main method, I have an array of threads which each thread is a `new OBJ`, and which each one, in the `run()` method, do a certain calculation and saves it in its count.

Now, I would like to have another loop (other than the loop I've started all my threads with), and for each thread wait for it to finish, and then use count getter to sum all the counts I've got from the threads.

How can I reach the getter through the threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, create your OBJ instances before you reach the threads loop :

```
List<OBJ> objects = new ArrayList<OBJ>();
// Create your objects here
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OBJ; ++i) {
   objects.add(new OBJ());
}

// Run the threads
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OBJ; ++i) {
   Thread t = new Thread(objects.get(i));
   threads.add(t);
   t.start();
}

// Wait for the threads to finish
for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.join();
}

// Sum all counts
int sum = 0;
for (OBJ object : objects) {
   sum += object.getCount();
}
```

Comment: @giorashc Sorry, missed that.  Wow.  A terrible answer and an incorrect comment.  Not my best moment.

Comment: No problem mate. we all are allowed to make mistakes :)

Answer (score 3):

Best way to accomplish would be to use an ExecutorService (see java.util.concurrent) with Callables, from which you can get the Futures.